# What software / methods to learn for nanophotonics (a branch of photonics) applications?

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-optics, software, photonics

I'm new to nanophotonics and been looking for some software and methods (Design, modelling, simulation .etc) used in this scientific field. I'll be grateful to know some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen most people using CST or COMSOL. I, personally, have more experience with the latter. MEEP has also been used, but it is more of a code library than UI-software.

Nanophotonics is old antenna theory+a bit of atomic optics+waveguides+nanofab. I would advise to also brush up on waveguides and free-space radiation, i.e. antennas (only basics). Atomic optics may come in handy, but only if you start hybridising with quantum dots etc.

Nonlinear optics, again basics, can also be useful. e.g. given a metamaterial with symmetry of a rectangle (D1), can you explain whether it will exhibit quadratic nonlinear response? What about hexagon (D6) or triangle (D3)?

A lot depends on whether you are more interested in integrated optics, i.e. waveguides, or free-space optics, e.g. metamaterials

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: @user668687, no worries. Good luck. BTW, some people also used Lumerical, though this is more for the integrated than free-space optics, but works in free-space as well. FDTD has some peculiarities though, mostly to do with meshing and (temporally) dispersive response